# karate - var in * configure headers don't work

Tags: karate

I'm trying to add var in `* configure headers` but it doesn't work.

If i write :

```
Given header Authorization = 'JWT '+setup.token
Given header Accept = 'application/json'
Given header Content = 'multipart/form-data'
```

it works so good !
BUT ! I want to put all "header" in `* configure headers` like this :

```
* configure headers =     
"""       
{         
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',         
'Authorization': 'JWT #(setup.token)',         
'Accept': 'application/json'       
}     
"""
```

in this case `setup.token` is not interpreted and return `1 > Authorization: JWT #(setup.token)`
in GET method

However, the syntax required to interpret a variable is that of the documentation.
Could you help me because I can’t figure out how to pass this variable into the code ?

Thank you ;-)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule for embedded expressions: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

So make this change (or use an intermediate variable):

```
* configure headers =     
"""       
{         
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',         
'Authorization': "#('JWT ' + setup.token)",         
'Accept': 'application/json'       
}     
"""
```